# Return a vector of row indices that correspond to the maximum of each row in a matrix or data.table

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, indices

This is a bit infuriating. I have a matrix (or data.table):

```
 effCF
effTKA  0  2000     4000      6000       8000     10000
  0     0 50000 68000.00 53999.997   7985.823 -62082.87
  2000  0 46000 60000.00 41999.966  -8048.204 -68108.25
  4000  0 42000 52000.00 29999.712 -24000.000 -69681.11
  6000  0 38000 44000.00 17998.000 -38871.369 -69957.42
  8000  0 34000 36000.00  5989.368 -49666.295 -69995.20
  10000 0 30000 27999.98 -6036.153 -54486.601 -69999.53
```

The rows correspond to 'effTKA' and the columns to effCF. The names of the dimensions are 0,2000,4000 etc.

What I want to do is to return two numeric vectors (or a 2x matrix) of:
1) The column indices corresponding to the maximum of each row, and
2) The column indices corresponding to the value of each row that is closest to zero but not corresponding to the first column.

So, in this example I would like to get:

```
[1] 4000 4000 4000 4000 4000 2000
[1] 8000 8000 8000 6000 6000 6000
```

I would need to perform this operation on larger tables. 
I also have a corresponding problem where I would need to do the same operations on another matrix, but finding the row indices that correspond to the maximum of each column.

I know how to do this by hand using which.max but I can't seem to figure out how to do it automatically.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Take a look at `?max.col` or `do.call(pmax, ...)`. For instance, compare `max.col(mtcars)` with `do.call(pmax, mtcars)`

Comment: I don't think matrices or data.tables print in exactly the way you have displayed. A concrete reproducible example might help here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/